# In Xamarin, does using a Portable Class Library mean you do not write platform specific code?

Tags: c#, xamarin, compilation

My understanding is the compiler directives in a Share Access Project (SAP) make use of platform specific code.

For SAP Xamarin has,

> Application projects can include platform-specific references that the
>   shared code can utilize (such as using Community.CsharpSqlite.WP7 in
>   the Tasky sample for Windows Phone).

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/#Shared_Projects

I didn't see anything on this page for PCL about *not* writing platform specific code.  If I include the Xamarin Android library in the PCL, is that not specific code that would be in a SAP?

Does it mean that I could tweak or have some feature on Android and Windows Phone that I couldn't on iOS (maybe iOS didn't support it?)

EDIT:  What does it look like to access the camera, for example, from PCL via DI, vs accessing the camera in a SAP (platform doesn't matter; Android is fine.)

Comment: You don't write platform code in the PCL - you generally access platform specific features from the PCL via DI or using the Bait-and-Switch pattern.

Comment: @Jason It looks like SAP is easier to understand, but that PCL is better for sharing and being more "future proof" and decoupled because of DI.

Comment: Nothing is future proof: PCLs are dead, long live the .NET Standard Library (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/articles/standard/library)